# How to split my dataframe value based on the prefix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe column has different value.I want to split the value which has prefix 172_ and update the same dataframe. Could someone help me here.

```
df_select['tradename_id']=['172_002000026440_AT','172_002000026440_CA','CA_CORPORATE1','CA_LYM_B']
df_select['tradename_id'].str.rsplit("_", n=1, expand=True)

Actual value :172_002000026440_AT
Expected value:172_002000026440
```

Comment: Try `expand=False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need set new values only by mask created by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), in `split` remove `expand=True` and select first lists by indexing `str[0]`:

```
df_select = pd.DataFrame({'tradename_id':['172_002000026440_AT','172_002000026440_CA',
                                          'CA_CORPORATE1','CA_LYM_B']})
```

---

```
m = df_select['tradename_id'].str.startswith('172_')
df_select.loc[m,'tradename_id'] = df_select.loc[m,'tradename_id'].str.rsplit("_", n=1).str[0]

print (df_select)
       tradename_id
0  172_002000026440
1  172_002000026440
2     CA_CORPORATE1
3          CA_LYM_B
```

Or use [`Series.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
m = df_select['tradename_id'].str.startswith('172_')
df_select['tradename_id'].update(df_select.loc[m,'tradename_id'].str.rsplit("_", n=1).str[0])

print (df_select)
       tradename_id
0  172_002000026440
1  172_002000026440
2     CA_CORPORATE1
3          CA_LYM_B
```